# from which view controller was send message prepareForSeague

Tags: ios

I have a `TabBarController` which has `2 TableViewControllers` with their own `save button` and `prepareForSegue` for each view. Pushing this button sends `prepareForSegue` message to the third `TableViewController` - which  is holding `TabBarController`.

I need to know which of 2 `TableViewController's` sent that message.

Comment: Have you tried `segue.sourceViewController`?

Comment: I didn't tried this one. Could you tell me, please, should I try to identify by this method ViewController's identity or something else? I can't quit figure it out